# Nativescript application events are not triggered

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have coded for application suspend & resume event within main.ts but the event does not get fired. I have followed the documentation from the following link https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/application-lifecycle#use-application-events

My Main.ts content for your reference

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import { on as applicationOn, suspendEvent, resumeEvent, ApplicationEventData } from "tns-core-modules/application";


applicationOn(suspendEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
    if (args.ios) {
        console.log("suspendEvent triggered");
    }
});

applicationOn(resumeEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
    if (args.ios) {
        console.log("resumeEvent triggered");
    }
});

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Which platform / OS version you are testing this against? Is it iOS specific?

Comment: We are testing against IOS 12.2. Yes it is IOS specific

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue, if you still face issues on your end please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Got it working, had something to do with the build. After removing the platforms and running a --clean build it started firing the events. Thanks